# Append two containers in constant time

Tags: c++, c++11

I am looking for a way to append two containers in constant (or at least minimal linear) time.

I noticed linked `list`s merge, but it seems to sort the elements. Isn't there a container/method to just re-link a container to another one (say, like `list1.last_element.next = list2.first_element`)?

Comment: "std::list is a container that supports constant time insertion and removal of elements from anywhere in the container." -- Are you sure that your list get sorted automatically?

Comment: "Merges x into the list by transferring all of its elements at their respective ordered positions into the container (both containers shall already be ordered)."

Comment: @AlexisWilke `std::list::merge` works on sorted lists and results in a sorted list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [std::list::splice](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) method:

```
std::list<int> list1;
std::list<int> list2;

list1.splice(list1.end(), list2, list2.begin(), list2.end());
```

This code appends the contents of the `list2` to the end of `list1`.

As Dietmar Kuhl mentioned, the method needs to count the elements in the range you are inserting:

```
[list2.begin(), list2.end())
```

so if you provide a range, the complexity is linear. However if you know that you want to append an **entire** list you can simply do

```
list1.splice(list1.end(), list2);
```

in `O(1)` time.

Comment: Note though that this is an `O(n)` operation and not `O(1)`

Answer (score 2):

For `std::list<T>` there is `splice()` which can be used to transfer nodes from one list to another list. Sadly, this method got broken to be linear in the length of the spliced sequenced when specifying a range of using two iterators and `splice()`ing between two `std:list<T>` object. This change was done in favor of having a constant time `size()` operation.

```
std::list<T> l1({ 1, 2, 3 });
std::list<T> l2({ 4, 5, 6 });
l1.splice(l1.end(), l2);
```

Comment: Destructive `splice`s like this are constant time, according to 23.3.6.5 in the spec...

Comment: I wonder how does the list know the number of elements in a range that it inserts in O(1) when the range comes from the same list.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Fair point: `splice()` is _only_ linear for the interesting case of `splice()`ing an iterator delimited range between two different lists.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: When `splice()`int within the same list there is no need to update the `size()`: since the nodes are transferred the `size()` doesn't change.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: it knows from the `size()` of the source list, since it is splicing the entire source list into the destination list.